# How to manipulate large media files in Node.js in a non-blocking way

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ffmpeg, file-handling, child-process

I am currently creating a Node.js app that receives an audio/video stream, writes it progressively to the disk, then transcodes it with ffmpeg once the stream has ended and sends it somewhere else to be stored, deleting it locally.

Besides the fact that I can transcode the stream before writing it to streamline the entire thing (this feature is planned), what is the best way to handle these operations on potentially large files?

I am aware of spawing child processes (the method I'm currently using), but I'm not sure how they actually function, even after much reading. I'm not even sure using "spawn" is exactly what I want here (is "fork" a better option?).

Essentially, I want to know how to transcode -> upload -> delete the file without blocking Node.js so that multiple users can do the same thing simultaneously. Also, I am thinking of putting all 3 operations in a single bash script so that they happen synchronously in sequential order, is this fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to handle this is to use [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) - a built in class in NodeJS.

streams allows piping data gradually and doing work on 1 chunk at a time. this allows handling files larger than the computer's RAM or endless stream of data like in your case.

so instead of writing the data to the disk, you can process it on the fly, without blocking the thread (can transcode multiple streams simultaneously).
You haven't shared any code, but here is a general example.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f mpegts -i pipe: -codec copy -f mpegts pipe:');
ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
    // upload a transcoded chunk
});

// if the source is also a stream you can pipe it directly like so
// sourceStream.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);

function onAudioVideoChunkReceived(chunk) {
    // handle audio/video input to nodejs server
    ffmpeg.stdin.write(chunk)
}
```

Note the use of the special input/output `pipe:` of ffmpeg that allows pipe input and output through stdin and stdout

Comment: Thank you, but transcoding on-the-fly is less my concern for the moment than understanding if spawn holds up the event loop while--let's say--transcoding the file. Essentially, I want to know if it's possible for multiple users to connect to this Node.js server I made, where files are transcoded in a child process by using spawn, or will the Node.js process be held up (disregarding external limits, like memory available and such)?

Comment: it doesn't block the thread and you can run multiple pipe at the same time. edited the answer to reflect that.
obviously this scales only up to a point where your CPU/memory/network are saturated.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know!